# If I say "four times zero four times one", is it correct way?

Tags: american-english, numbers, speech

I want to know if someone asks me about wifi password and it was 0000 1111, how could I say it as an American man?

Comment: You could say "four zeros, then four ones", or "zero zero, zero zero, one one, one one", or various other ways.  I wouldn't say "four times zero", as that sounds too much like a sum (ie "four times zero equals zero").

Comment: Following the way British people tend to say telephone numbers, you could say:Double-oh,Double-oh  Double one, double one.

Comment: Just say "15 in 8 digit binary". Make them work for it.

Comment: alternative: zero four times then one four times. But not: four times zero which means: four multiplied by zero.

Comment: "Zero fox in binary"

Comment: Thanx  i think its the best way to say it

Answer (score 2):

From my experience I am inclined to think that the typical american man would most likely say "four zeros, then four ones", but that doesn't make it the best way to express a password in English, especially one consisting entirely of numbers. Usually, passwords are not sentences, instead they are a single term consisting of a string of characters that are free of grammar rules. To express a non-sentence password in the form of a sentence (or even a sentence fragment), as in "four zeros, then four ones", increases the likelihood of confusion. The listener is unexpectedly forced to interpret grammar rules in order to apprehend the response accurately.

In this example, the listener must determine that "four" is a numerical adjective that modifies the numerical nouns "zeros" and "ones". There is a good chance that the listener will incorrectly, yet understandably, mistake "four" as a character in the password term. In English, the best way to say a password, consisting of a string of numbers, is to say each individual number as in, "zero zero zero zero one one one one". It takes longer to say than "four ones, then four zeros", but it's quicker than repeating yourself to clarify that you meant, "the number zero, four times, and then the number one, four times".

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, people don't typically phrase long strings of numbers like that. Generally, you would say "zero zero zero zero one one one one," or, commonly, group the numbers into two digit numerals (when applicable), as in "zero zero zero zero eleven eleven." Sometimes, you may hear two consecutive numbers, especially zeros, referred to as "double oh" or "double zero," as in, "double oh double oh eleven eleven." There are many different ways to handle it, depending on how many digits there are, whether there are letters in the string, etc. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if someone asks me about wifi password and it was 0000 1111, how could I say it as an American man?

My American father might have said: "**double-aught, double-aught, eleven-eleven**."

> [aught (n.2): "nothing, zero," faulty separation of a naught (see naught).](http://aught%20(n.2)%20%20%22nothing,%20zero,%22%20faulty%20separation%20of%20a%20naught%20(see%20naught).)

I'd say it that way too, if I thought there was a slim chance someone might [understand](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Nuremberg_chronicles_f_65r_3.png) me.

Comment: How old is your father?  I've never heard aught used that way in America, except in old plays, when referring to events that happened in the first 10 years of the 20th century  (Like "The Music Man, which takes place in 1912)

Comment: "Sizes larger than "0" ("aught") are designated by multiple zeros. "00" ("double-aught") is the most commonly used size." (Wikipedia, on the subject of buckshot). My father was born in 1935, but his family has been American since around 1635. And he used the term "aught" to mean zero, quite regularly.